# NSDate Not Equal After Conversion To and From NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to store and retrieve dates to/from JSON. NSDates created from identical string fail `isEqualToDate:`. This is certainly due to floating point precision issue, but I'm not sure how to work around it.

Given two identical input strings to `dateFromString:`, resulting `NSDate` objects *should* be equal:

```
NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
NSString *string1 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date1];
NSDate *dateA = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string1];
NSDate *dateB = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string1];
XCTAssertTrue([dateA isEqualToDate:dateB]);
```

...but, in reality the resulting date objects are lucky to be equal (and rarely are), since there's random cruft introduced due to floating point precision issues:

```
(lldb) p [dateA timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
(NSTimeInterval) $4 = 560455653.79073596
(lldb) p [dateB timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
(NSTimeInterval) $5 = 560455653.79099989
```

So, anyone encounter this and workaround it? The only option I have thought of is to write my own `isEquals:` but that's not ideal.

---

EDIT:

Specifically what I'm looking for is a way to convert a string representation of a date back into a date object which will be considered equal for the same input string.

The (apparent) fact that `NSDate` stores its internal state in a floating point number is irrelevant in that Foundation should provide a mechanism to achieve parity for output dates when given identical inputs (i.e. the same string in should yield objects which are equal). Either Foundation offers this and I'm missing it (and hopeful that the SO community knows something about Foundation I don't), or Foundation is buggy (in this case) and I'm looking to the SO community for a workaround I hadn't already considered.

EDIT 2:

Apologies, my question, as originally asked, is nonsense. In an attempt to simplify the issue for this post I introduced an unintended comparison between two numbers which could not possibly be equal.

Original nonsense post, for posterity:

> I'm trying to store and retrieve dates to/from JSON. The `NSDate` I store into JSON fails `isEqualToDate:` on the `NSDate` object I recreate from the stored string. This is certainly due to floating point precision issue, but I'm not sure how to work around it.
>   Specifically:
>
> ```
> NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
> dateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0];
> dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc]
> initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
> dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'";
> NSDate *date1 = [NSDate date];
> NSString *string1 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date1];
> NSDate *date2 = [dateFormatter dateFromString:string1];
> NSString *string2 = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date2];
> // This test passes
> XCTAssertTrue([string1 isEqualToString:string2]);
> // This test fails
> XCTAssertTrue([date1 isEqualToDate:date2]);
> // This test fails
> XCTAssertTrue([date1 isEqual:date2]);
> ```
>
> Looking at `date1` and `date2` in the debugger we see the difference:
>
> ```
> (lldb) p [date1 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
> 560363055.21521103
>
> (lldb) p [date2 timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]
> 560363055.21499991
> ```
>
> (note the thousandth's place)
>
> `NSDate`'s `isEqual:` (and variant) is almost certainly comparing the
>   instances' time offsets, and thus failing.
>
> I have tried adding more precision to the stored string (i.e.
>   `.SSSSSS`) but this does not seem to have an impact.
>
> So, anyone encounter this and workaround it? The only option I have
>   thought of is to write my own `isEquals:` but that's not ideal.

Comment: It isn't valid to compare, for equality, an `NSDate` created from the system clock and an `NSDate` reconstituted from a string in this way. It is like asking "why isn't a float saved as a string to 3  decimal places and converted back to a float equal to the original float?"  You shouldn't perform an equality test on a reconstituted date and a clock-derived date. It is essentially just like any other floating point based comparison

Answer (score 5):

tl;dr - you are trying to compare nanoseconds to milliseconds. Those results won't be the same.

When you create an `NSDate` with `[NSDate date];` you get a value that includes fractional seconds to a precision of microseconds, or maybe even nanoseconds.

When you convert the date to a string with format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS` you are creating a string with exactly 3 decimal places (milliseconds). And then when you convert that string back to an `NSDate`, you get a floating point number that approximates those milliseconds as best as can be represented.

So you have the original date with a precision of micro or nano seconds and the second date is only to milliseconds. Of course the two dates will be different due to the different level of precision. This has nothing to do with floating point numbers. Even if you have perfect floating point numbers, you are comparing 100.123456789 to 100.123. They are not the same number.

You stated that you tried using `SSSSSS` instead of `SSS` but `NSDateFormatter` doesn't honor anything more than three fractional digits so anything beyond `SSS` is wasted effort.

With that explanation out of the way, what solutions do you have to compare your two dates?

One is to compare the two dates only to three decimal places. Here is a helpful little `NSDate` category method that does just that:

```
@interface NSDate (extra)

- (BOOL)isEqualToDateMilliseconds:(NSDate *)otherDate;

@end

@implementation NSDate (extra)

- (BOOL)isEqualToDateMilliseconds:(NSDate *)otherDate {
    TimeInterval secs1 = [self timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
    TimeInterval secs2 = [self timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

    return abs(secs1 - secs2) < 0.001;
}

@end
```

Use a better category name if your own code.

Now you can replace:

```
XCTAssertTrue([date1 isEqualToDate:date2]);
```

with:

```
XCTAssertTrue([date1 isEqualToDateMilliseconds:date2]);
```

and you will get the proper result.

Comment: Your method doesn't work as you intend. Two floating-point values can be less than 1/1000th apart but still round in different directions. Use `fabsf(a - b) < 0.001`.

Comment: Can you cite a reference to your comment about `NSDateFormatter` not honoring additional precision? I see Apple's docs referencing this doc, which gives a `1-n` for the number of `S` format specifiers (implying no limit). http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Yep, I'm aware I can implement my own `isEquals:` thanks.

Comment: That's the spec. The implementation of `[NS]DateFormatter` only works up to `SSS`. It's not documented. It's just a fact learned from experience.

Comment: So, not "spec", just anecdotal.

Comment: I was referring to the link you posted. That's the official specification (spec). `NSDateFormatter` doesn't quite honor the spec fully.

Answer (score 1):

Because NSDates underlying storing is a float I don't think there is any way to use NSDateFormatter without some loss of precision. If you want to be able to use isEqualToDate: you can try storing the dates as floats using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate (or timeIntervalSince1970). But then the problem is isEqualToDate: can only tell you if two dates are close enough that any difference is less than that representable by floating point number, is that really what you want to treat as equal, or would you rather treat two dates as equivalent if they are less then a second apart of a millisecond apart, I can imagine that there are situations where you do want to use isEqualToDate: but then you should be using timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate not NSDateFormatter which is a way to parse and generate human readable strings not store data in a lossy format.

Comment: Thanks. I think perhaps my intent was not clear. I do not consider the date format I have specified to be "lossy." The precision of the stored date is absolute. The issue is the underlying implementation of NSDate suffers from floating point memory issues

Comment: @levigroker `NSDate` has no "floating point memory issues". The problem is the loss of precision from the string. The string only has 3 decimal places but the original `NSDate` has many more than that. This is all covered in my answer.

Comment: @rmaddy you say it *in* your answer "a floating point number that approximates those three decimal places" How is that not a floating point memory issue?

Comment: @levigroker But the issues isn't a factor of the inability of floating point numbers to precisely represent every possible floating point number. The issue is caused solely by your code trying to compare a number generated with higher precision with a number generated from a string with much less precision. Your problem would exist even with perfect floating point numbers.

Comment: "Your problem would exist even with perfect floating point numbers." read that out loud slowly to yourself.

Comment: @levigroker What? I meant exactly what I said. The problem is you are convinced the problem is due to floating point number issues. But it isn't.  I've clarified my answer to make this clear. Please review it again.

Comment: It not a case of whether you are specify a date formatter to be lossy, it whether NSDateFormatter itself is designed to be lossy, its designed to parse and generate human readable strings, is it really designed to do what you want, because of the underlining data of a date is a double the precision depends of how close the date is to the reference date 1970 or 2001 or what ever it is, within a second and the precision will be over 10^-17 of a second, NSDateFormatter might only go to milli seconds or micro seconds.

Comment: I just confirmed using a date format pattern of yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSS'Z', that's 5 'S' and using two date strings that are identical except for the very last digit the exact same NSDate is produced. So NSDateFormatter will only parses up to micro seconds.